# Make Jekyll process Sass in any directory?

Tags: css, sass, jekyll

I'm working on a demo site with a bunch of one-off pages. Rather than have them all use the same CSS they'll each have their own stylesheets (with possibly a shared reset). I know I can just put a CSS file into whatever directory and it's fine, but it doesn't seem to work for Sass files.

Is there a way to get Jekyll to process any Sass file regardless of what directory it's in? Or at least in any directory within a certain folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be that you don't have any front-matter on your files if they're just in the `css/` directory of your project.

Check out an example project here: [`css/main_css_file.scss`](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-sass-converter/blob/master/example/css/main_css_file.scss), and have a read of this relevant part of the docs entitled "[Assets](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/assets/#sassscss)"

> Jekyll allows you to customize your Sass conversion in certain ways.
>
> Place all your partials in your `sass_dir`, which defaults to `<source>/_sass`. Place your main SCSS or Sass files in the place you want them to be in the output file, such as `<source>/css`. For an example, take a look at [this example site using Sass support in Jekyll](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-sass-converter/tree/master/example).
>
> If you are using Sass `@import` statements, you’ll need to ensure that your `sass_dir` is set to the base directory that contains your Sass files. You can do that thusly:
>
> ```
> sass:
>     sass_dir: _sass
> ```
>
> The Sass converter will default the `sass_dir` configuration option to `_sass`.

^ You may like to refer to the above if you want to inline the reset for each sheet. `<source>/_sass` or whatever you configure for `sass_dir` in the config could be it's home. (Although: you'd probably get a performance boost out of including it separately, so the browser could cache it between requests.)

Comment: That is 100% what it was: I was missing the front matter. But it does not appear to matter what directory they're in so long as that's there.